# splice not working with a array row vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, delete-row, splice

I have a Object array but when i want remove a object from array list only items are deleted from the end

```
<div class="hours" v-for="(time, index) in hour" :key="index">
```

then I put the click function on an icon

```
<b-icon
v-if="time.delete"
icon="x"
width="20"
height="20"
class="delete-time"
@click="deleteTime(index)"
></b-icon>
```

but when I go to do the delete

```
methods: {
moment, 
deleteTime(index) {
       this.hour.splice(index, 1);
 },
```

Comment: why dont you just go with `this.hour.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: tried but it doesn't work ...

Comment: What error are you getting when trying that? `this.hour.indexOf(index)` will return undefined. Also, why are you binding in `:key` to `time.index` instead of simply to `index`? On anotehr note, it's not a good idea to use index (which could change due to sorting) for the key attribute. Use a property of the object, preferably something like a unique ID

Comment: i left as: key only index as you told me, i can't use another property because it doesn't have any

Comment: Is `hour` present within the `data`? [If not, Vue.js won't track changes](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods). Have you tried logging both `hour` and `index` within `deleteItem()`? Are they what you would expect them to be? Could you add the logged values of both `hour` and `index` to the question?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that the challenge is that you need to add a unique id in **HOUR**, as you had earlier.
I have updated my previous answer

```
 hour: [
            {
              id: 1,
              "item-1": 10,
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              "item-2": 11,
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              "item-3": 12,
            },
          ],
```

Take note that **key** is assigned to the unique id gotten from the **hour** object.

```
:key="time.id"
```

And **deleteItems** takes **index** has a parameter

```
@click="deleteTime(index)"
```

```
      <div class="hours" v-for="(time, index) in hour" :key="time.id">
        <button @click="deleteTime(index)">
          Content {{time.id}}
        </button>
      </div>
```

Then your method goes

```
deleteTime(index) {
            this.hour.splice(index, 1);
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
deleteTime(index) {
       this.hour.splice(index, 1);
 },
```

Comment: it doesn't give me any error in the console but it always deletes the last line

Comment: What is the value of index?

Comment: the index changes according to the line they want to delete

Comment: Could you please create a code sandbox and share the link

Answer (score 0):

this should work, always add an id for tracking, btw if you used splice here it will work also

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    hour: [
      { id: 1, name: "one" },
      { id: 2, name: "two" },
      { id: 3, name: "three" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    deleteTime(id) {
      this.hour = this.hour.filter(item => item.id != id);
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>

<div id ="app">
  <div class="hours" v-for="(time, index) in hour" :key="index">
    {{ time.name }}
    <button @click="deleteTime(time.id)">del</button>
  </div>
</div>
```